# Is magnetic reconnection possible in vacuum?

Tags: electromagnetism, vacuum, maxwell-equations, plasma-physics

Magnetic reconnection occurs due to flux-breaking behaviour (e.g. finite resistivity) in a medium. But can reconnection be observed in a vacuum (where there may be virtual particles)? Has this been observed?

Comment: If you allow reconnection to include any change in field topology, then the answer is yes.  This cannot be observed because there is no where that is a vacuum.  The closest thing to a vacuum are the magnetospheres of magnetized planets but even those have a finite number of particles.

Comment: @honeste_vivere "If you allow reconnection to include any change in field topology, then the answer is yes." - How can topology be broken if there is no mechanism to break flux conservation in a vacuum? Or is there an available mechanism?